# 12.10 Running slowly

Tags: 12.10

I'm new to Ubuntu and have installed 12.10 on a laptop that previously had Windows Vista. I installed 12.10 choosing to use the whole C: drive - so in at the deep end! However, 12.10 runs with a 4 or 5 second lag when it is at its quickest.  It also doesn't recognize the USB ports (although there is still power through them). The machine has 1.5 gig RAM.

I have tried reinstalling twice. Any ideas on what I should do?  Does 12.04 need less juice to run it?  If so, should I try installing 12.04?

Any advice very welcome!

Comment: I run 12.10 on an old Dell laptop, I installed gnome session fall back because Unity was too resource hungry. Also look into your start up programs. I found this site useful https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. We need to know more about your PC to troubleshoot your problem. RAM isn't everything. May I ask what CPU/GPU you are using? Please edit your post with these details so that other users will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 12.04 & if you think 12.10 is slow , 12.04 is turtle for me it takes 13 seconds to boot on a laptop with ivy bride core i5 CPU ! I think wait 20 days for 13.04 release & try it .

Comment: not even 13.04, I came to know that the new version like 14.04 onwards will be based on QT only and mobile and desktop interfaces will be same.

Comment: Not certain this helps OP